Sveltekit app doesn't load .svelte files when hosted
I am building a site with Sveltekit and in-IDE tests (npm run build) show things fine, the routing works and pages display correctly. However when I've tried to upload the app to a dev site provided to me the framework doesn't seem to load.
It loads app.html but doesn't seem to pick up that it's a sveltekit program, instead only displaying '%sveltekit.head% %sveltekit.body%'
Here's my app.html:


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        %sveltekit.head%
    </head>
    <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
        <div style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>
    </body>
</html>



I'm inexperienced in both sveltekit and FTP hosting so I'm wondering if I've uploaded the wrong file to the server? On fileZilla (and when testing with vs-code sftp extension) I've mostly tried uploading the whole app folder but is this incorrect?

app.html is the source file, not the built output.
You need to upload the files that SvelteKit generates on build.
If you deploy via FTP, this sounds like you have a static file server. If so you should check out the docs on static site generation. SSG requires using the adapter from @sveltejs/adapter-static which will by default output the result to a build directory which is what you should upload.

I see, thank you. I've installed and applied the static adapter and added export const prerender = true; to routes/+layout.js (a file I needed to create for this)
On build it makes/ updates the .svelte-kit folder.. is this the build folder? I can't find a folder actually called 'build'
I tried just uploading the .svelte-kit folder and it didn't work, [address]/.svelte-kit gives 403 everything else 404

Update! adding /.svelte-kit to the address now loads the main page, just without any external files (all images missing, global stylesheet etc). Also all routes (other than '/') are still giving 404. What's up now? Sorry for these basic questions

You should not mess with .svelte-kit that contains internal, intermediate files. As stated, read the linked docs and deploy the build directory.
